# dijit.InlineEditBox with highlighted html

Tags: dojo, highlight, inlineeditbox

I have some dijit.InlineEditBox widgets and now I need to add some search highlighting over them, so I return the results with a span with class="highlight" over the matched words. The resulting code looks like this :

```
<div id="title_514141" data-dojo-type="dijit.InlineEditBox" 
     data-dojo-props="editor:\'dijit.form.TextBox\', onFocus:titles.save_old_value, 
     onChange:titles.save_inline, renderAsHtml:true">Twenty Thousand Leagues <span 
     class="highlight">Under</span> the Sea</div>
```

This looks as expected, however, when I start editing the title the added span shows up. How can I make the editor remove the span added so only the text remains ?

In this particular case the titles of the books have no html in them, so some kind of full tag stripping should work, but it would be nice to find a solution (in case of short description field with a dijit.Editor widget perhaps) where the existing html is left in place and only the highlighting span is removed.

Also, if you can suggest a better way to do this (inline editing and word highlighting) please let me know.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

How will this affect your displayed content in the editor? It rather depends on the contents you allow into the field - you will need a rich-text editor (huge footprint) to handle html correctly.

These RegExp's will trim away XML tags

```
this.value = this.displayNode.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/, " ").replace(/<\/[^>]*>/, '');
```

Here's a running example of the below code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/5eNSC/)

```
<div id="title_514141" data-dojo-type="dijit.InlineEditBox" 
     data-dojo-props="editor:\'dijit.form.TextBox\', onFocus:titles.save_old_value, 
     onChange:titles.save_inline, renderAsHtml:true">Twenty Thousand Leagues <span 
     class="highlight">Under</span> the Sea

 <script type="dojo/method" event="onFocus">
   this.value = this.displayNode.innerHTML.
      replace(/<[^>]*>/, " ").
      replace(/<\/[^>]*>/, '');
   this.inherited(arguments);
 </script>
</div>
```

The renderAsHtml attribute only trims 'off one layer', so embedded HTML will still be html afaik. With the above you should be able to 1) override the `onFocus` handling, 2) set the editable value yourself and 3) call 'old' `onFocus` method.

Alternatively (as seeing you have allready set 'titles.save_*' in props, use `dojo/connect` instead of `dojo/method` - but you need to get there first, sort of say.